# use of PARALLEL in make

Tags: makefile

I have been working on makefiles and trying to reduce their compilation time. The structure of the my code consists of various sub directories each having its own makefile. The subdirectories in the main directory seem to be independent as whenever i run make in any of the subdirectories, it runs perfectly fine and shows no error. Thus, i want to run the sub-make for all subdirectories in parallel. Is it possible> and if yes, how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but would it be too much effort to switch to non-recursive make? See http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crude but effective method:

```
SUBDIRS = /something /something/else /another

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS) all

all: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    @$(MAKE) -s -C $@
```

Run this with `make -j`.